# understanding distribution function of wrapped distr.?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am reading books about wrapped distributions and am now on the definition of distribution function of wrapped distr. In the definition I am using is difference between $F(\theta + 2k\pi) - F(2k\pi)$. I am thinking that to defining it like that and subtract every term by $F(2k\pi)$ is simply because we wanna stay in arc of length $2\pi$. But maybe there is another reason?

The definition I am using is the following

**Definition:**
Given a distribution on the line, we can wrap it around the circumference of the circle of unit radius. That is, if $x$ is a random variable on the line with d.f. $F(x)$, the random variable $x_w$ of the wrapped distribution is given by
$$
x_w = x\pmod{2\pi} \tag{ 3.4.21}
$$
and the d.f. of $x_w$ is given by
$$
F_w(\theta) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \{F(\theta + 2\pi k) - F(2\pi k)\}, \quad 0<\theta\leq 2\pi  \tag{3.4.22}
$$

<sub>[(Picture version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu2kD.png)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(3.4.21) is vague and permits more that one interpretation.

In this answer I choose for: $$x_w\in(0,2\pi]\wedge \frac{x-x_w}{2\pi}\in\mathbb Z$$

For $\theta\in(0,2\pi]$ on base of (3.4.21) we have:$$\{x_w\leq\theta\}=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}\{2\pi k<x\leq2\pi k+\theta\}$$

The sets in the union on RHS are disjoint so consequently:$$P(x_w\leq\theta)=P(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}\{2\pi k<x\leq2\pi k+\theta\})=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}P(2\pi k<x\leq2\pi k+\theta)$$

or using the notation of CDF's:$$F_{x_w}(\theta)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\left[F_x(2\pi k+\theta)-F_x(2\pi)\right]$$

Things can be made complete (formally a CDF is defined on $\mathbb R$) by stating that: $$F_{x_w}(\theta)=0\text{ if }\theta\leq0\text{ and }F_{x_w}(\theta)=1\text{ if }\theta>2\pi$$

---

I do not exclude that this was allready clear to you. If so then please specify what is not.

Comment: thanks very much, moreless it´s precisely what i was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome.